# Load specific page after Application outh redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

So, I am using https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&scope=email&redirect_uri=xx to allow me access to users' details.

I want to then direct users to the app, and load specific page within my tab. This is where I become stuck...

My tab URL is in the following format:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/mysite/xxxx?sk=app_xxx

Is there something I can to this URL to make it load a specific URL?
(the app is always in the tab)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define which page you want your tab to load you can use an additional parameter called app_data in the url to your tab, eg

http://www.facebook.com/MY_PAGE?sk=app_MY_APP_ID&app_data=A_STRING_OF_DATA

Your tab will then receive this as part of the signed_request, you can grab it and use it to work out which page your tab needs to display.